# Consulta SQL que devuelve fechas no existentes en el resultado de la propia consulta

Tags: c#, sql, informix

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos en Informix. Accedo a ella desde una aplicación web desarrollada con C#.

En una tabla llamada MC_turnosAgenda tengo varios registros, de los cuales quiero obtener únicamente el campo fecha, utilizando DISTINCT para obtener una sola vez cada valor, cumpliendo con la siguiente condición:

- Estado distinto de 0.

Para hacerlo, ejecuto la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(turno_fecha) fecha
FROM MC_turnosAgenda
WHERE turno_estado <> 0 AND
 (turno_fecha NOT IN (SELECT turno_fecha FROM MC_turnosAgenda WHERE 
 turno_estado = 0))
```

Hasta ahí lo tengo resuelto. La consulta me devuelve una lista de fechas, ej: 20/07/2017, 24/07/2017, 01/08/2017, 03/08/2017, etc. Estas fechas las paso a un control de calendario para que aparezcan como NO DISPONIBLES.

Lo que necesito hacer: además de las fechas que obtengo con la consulta anterior, necesito incluir en esa lista todas las fechas que NO aparecen en esa consulta. Es decir, si la consulta me devuelve las fecha 02/08/2017 y 04/08/2017, y no existe ningún registro con fecha, por ejemplo, 03/08/2017, incluir esa fecha también. Aclaro que hay una fecha inferior y una fecha máxima entre las cuales buscar.

No se si hay forma de hacerlo o si en lugar de hacerlo por SQL conviene buscar alguna forma de hacerlo desde el código C# de la aplicación.

Comment: Si quieres unir los resultados de varias consultas te pondrán servir las siguientes operadores de conjunto UNION, EXCEPT e INTERSECT.
(https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ff848745(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: que vas a hacer con las otras fechas???

Comment: En `MC_turnosAgenda` tienes todas las fechas posibles, es decir tienes todos los días de cada mes estén ocupados o no?

Comment: @gbianchi la idea es: el calendario por defecto tiene todas las fechas habilitadas. Yo le paso las fechas a deshabilitar obteniendolas con la consulta en cuestion. Con las otras fechas no hago nada.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho no. A veces habra fechas marcadas como no disponibles (estado 2) pero puede que la aplicación que genera los registros de fechas no haya generado. Es decir, en la tabla voy a tener las fechas disponibles, las no disponibles pero tambien pueden faltar algunas no disponibles por no haber sido generados los registros.

Comment: entonces me parece que lo mejor es poner todas las fechas como disponibles, y en una segunda pasada agregar las no disponibles.. yo no haria un query complicado para eso...

Comment: Una tabla de BD que existe sólo para calcular que fechas hay en un intervalo es una mala práctica; no te da ninguna información y solo sirve para crearte problemas (por ejemplo, si no se ha registrado una fecha o alguien la borra) y ralentizar el procesamiento. Como @gbianchi explica, no todo tiene que ser SQL.

Comment: Tu consulta es redundante obtienes las fechas que tienen estatus en 0 y verificas que no exista en el rango de fechas que tienen un estatus diferente a 0, Creo que el problema esta en tu logicá de negocio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor solución ya te la han dicho en los comentarios, si tienes alguna interfaz tipo calendario, simplemente marcando todos los días por defecto como disponibles, y solo marcar los no disponibles con tu consulta, sería lo más óptimo.

Pero si tienes algún tipo de restricción y no tienes otra salida que construir todos los días de un determinado período obviamente a tu consulta debieras agregarle otra para obtener los días adicionales. Como has comentado que no tienes el todas las fechas en tabla entonces el problema implícito en tu pregunta es:

#### Como generar una secuencia de datos de forma dinámica.

Hay múltiples posibilidades para hacer esto, la que se podría pensar rápidamente es un `WHILE LOOP` y una inserción en una tabla temporal de todos los registros de fecha desde un `FechaDesde` hasta un `FechaHasta` sin embargo es recomendable evitar estos ciclos por cuestiones de performance, fuera de eso hay varias opciones, te recomiendo la lectura de [este artículo](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) que si bien aplica a **SQL server** muchos trucos podrían ser aplicados a **Informix**.

El truco que vamos a usar es trabajar con tablas dinámicas de 10 valores que "multiplicaremos" usando `CROSS JOIN` algunas veces para construir un una secuencia incremental de números, este numero sumándolo en días a nuestra `fechadesde` nos dará cada una de las fechas del período solicitado. Te adjunto este [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83259/1) en **SQL Server** a modo de ejemplo. Tener en cuenta que el ejemplo logra "mapear" hasta un máximo de 10.000 días, se puede ir aumentándolo eventualmente sumando más sentencias `CROSS JOIN`.

En **informix** sería más o menos así, tené en cuenta que hace bastantes años que no veo un Script en este dialecto de SQL, por lo que pude haber cometido algún error:

```
DECLARE  v_FechaDesde   DATE
DECLARE  v_FechaHasta   DATE

SELECT  v_FechaDesde    = '20170101'
SELECT  v_FechaHasta    = '20170630'

SELECT  v_FechaDesde + ((A.A*1000) + (B.A*100) + (C.A*10) + D.A) UNITS DAY
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS A UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS A
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS A UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS B
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS A UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS C
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS A UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS D
    WHERE v_FechaDesde + ((A.A*1000) + (B.A*100) + (C.A*10) + D.A) UNITS DAY <= v_FechaDesde
ORDER BY 1
```

Lo que deberías hacer una vez generada esta secuencia es lo siguiente:

1. Filtrar de la secuencia de fechas, aquellas que ya están en tu
   consulta mediante un simple `NOT IN (<tu consulta>)`
2. Unir ambas consultas mediante un `UNION`

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me resultó muy útil tu respuesta.