# Consulta BD Oracle por segmentos de horas

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Hola tengo una tabla en BD Oracle que tiene los siguientes campos y valores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora necesito generar una consulta que me agrupe por tramos de media hora el número de elementos por FECHA_CREACION, por ejemplo para este caso el resultado que esperaria seria:

```
 Hora               Total
 10/7 14:00-14:30   3
 10/7 14:30-15:00   0
 10/7 15:00-15:30   0
 ...
 11/7 11:00-11:30   1
```

pero no encuentro una forma de hacerlo,
alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Importante**: **Oracle** no es el dialecto de `SQL` que uso a diario, por lo que seguramente la solución que te prepongo tal vez no sea la mejor ya que es una adaptación de una forma de resolverlo en **SQL Server**.

Esta pregunta tiene un problema similar a [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86021/consulta-sql-que-devuelve-fechas-no-existentes-en-el-resultado-de-la-propia-cons/86189#86189) que tiene que ver con la necesidad de generar una secuencia de períodos a medir en este caso de 30 minutos. El primer tema es definir la ventana de tiempo, el desde/hasta que queremos medir, con esa ventana de tiempo generaremos una tabla de `Periodos` con un registro por cada 30 minutos, son 48 registros si elegimos listar un solo día, 96 si son dos, etc.

Lo podemos hacer así:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE Periodos (
    PeriodoId          NUMBER,
    DesdeFechaHora     DATE,
    HastaFechaHora     DATE,
    Descripcion        VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Periodos (PeriodoId,DesdeFechaHora,HastaFechaHora)
SELECT
  level,
  (to_date('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + 1/48 * (level -1)),
  (to_date('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + 1/48 * (level   ))
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 48 * 2;


UPDATE  Periodos
    SET Descripcion = TO_CHAR(DesdeFechaHora,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || TO_CHAR(DesdeFechaHora, 'HH24:MI:SS') || '-' || TO_CHAR(HastaFechaHora, 'HH24:MI:SS');
```

Lo que hacemos es generar lo períodos de dos días `LEVEL <= 48 * 2` desde el `2017-01-01`. Si vemos un resumen de la salida, podemos darnos cuenta como vamos a usar esta tabla:

```
PERIODOID   DESDEFECHAHORA          HASTAFECHAHORA          DESCRIPCION
1           2017-01-01T00:00:00Z    2017-01-01T00:30:00Z    2017-01-01 00:00:00-00:30:00
2           2017-01-01T00:30:00Z    2017-01-01T01:00:00Z    2017-01-01 00:30:00-01:00:00
3           2017-01-01T01:00:00Z    2017-01-01T01:30:00Z    2017-01-01 01:00:00-01:30:00
```

Ahora como prueba de concepto armamos una tabla de ejemplo

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE Ejemplo (
    Fecha              DATE
);

INSERT INTO Ejemplo (Fecha) VALUES (TO_DATE('2017-01-01 09:05','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO Ejemplo (Fecha) VALUES (TO_DATE('2017-01-01 09:15','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO Ejemplo (Fecha) VALUES (TO_DATE('2017-01-01 09:31','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO Ejemplo (Fecha) VALUES (TO_DATE('2017-01-01 10:12','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
```

Y la consulta final mediante un `LEFT JOIN` nos permite obtener las cantidades de fechas entre períodos y además saber que períodos no registran movimientos

```
SELECT  P.Descripcion,
        COUNT(E.Fecha)
        FROM Periodos P
        LEFT JOIN Ejemplo E
            ON E.Fecha >= P.DesdeFechaHora
            AND E.Fecha < P.HastaFechaHora
        GROUP BY P.Descripcion, P.PeriodoId
        ORDER BY P.PeriodoId;
```

Y un extracto de la salida:

```
DESCRIPCION                     COUNT(E.FECHA)
2017-01-01 08:30:00-09:00:00    0
2017-01-01 09:00:00-09:30:00    2
2017-01-01 09:30:00-10:00:00    1
2017-01-01 10:00:00-10:30:00    1
2017-01-01 10:30:00-11:00:00    0
```

Espero te sirva..

Comment: Muchas muchas gracias, esto lo ha resuelto, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

he implementado otra solución valida, ya que estoy usando JPA con Hibernate dejo la Query como la hago ahí en JAVA con JPA por si a alguien le sirve.

```
 @Query(value="select to_char(trunc(fecha,'HH')+(30*round(to_char( trunc(fecha,'MI'),'MI')/30))/1440,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi') AS fecha, SUM(total) AS total "
        + "from ConteoConsultasVWByFecha  "
        + "WHERE fecha BETWEEN TO_DATE(:fechaDesde, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE(:fechaHasta, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') "
        + "GROUP BY to_char(trunc(fecha,'HH')+(30*round(to_char( trunc(fecha,'MI'),'MI')/30))/1440,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi') "
        + "ORDER BY fecha ASC"
    )
List<Map<String, Long>> findAllByHour(@Param("fechaDesde") String fechaDesde,@Param("fechaHasta")  String fechaHasta);
```

Esto me trae los campos que necesito asociados a grupos de tramas por intervalos de 30 minutos, para un intervalo de fechas (por eso el Between) cabe resaltar que si son muuuchos registros habrá que colocar un limitador.